# UWP webview slows the app

Tags: webview, win-universal-app

I have multiple webviews on one page, when app loads, the main page stucks for almost 8-10 seconds, I am guesing tht is the time taken by all webviews to load respective websites, why does Ui stucks, how can I make loading of webviews asyncronous so that Ui remains responsive?

Comment: i have only one and it still sucks i think moving to webview2 is better alternative https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/

Answer (score 0):

you can try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/web-view#threading-behavior and move the processing to a different thread or process it did help me a bit but not much https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webviewexecutionmode?view=winrt-19041